# Mongodb: how to auto-increment a subdocument field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

The following document records a conversation between Milhouse and Bart. I would like to insert a new message with the right num (the next in the example would be 3) in a unique operation. Is that possible ?

```
    {   user_a:"Bart",
        user_b:"Milhouse",
        conversation:{
            last_msg:2,
            messages:[
                {   from:"Bart",
                    msg:"Hello"
                    num:1
                },
                {   from:"Milhouse",
                    msg:"Wanna go out ?"
                    num:2
                }
            ]
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, arrays keep their order, so by adding a `num` attribute, you're only creating more data for something that you could accomplish without the additional field. Just use the position in the array to accomplish the same thing. Grabbing the X message in an array will provide faster searches than searching for `{ num: X }`.

To keep the order, I don't think there's an easy way to add the `num` category besides does a `find()` on `conversation.last_msg` before you insert the new subdocument and increment `last_msg`.

Depending on what you need to keep the ordering for, you might consider including a time stamp in your subdocument, which is commonly kept in conversation records anyway and may provide other useful information.

Also, I haven't used it, but there's a Mongoose plugin that may or may not be able to do what you want: https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: Once I extracted the messages I want for using them outside mongo context, I loose the information. I want every message object to carry its rank in the conversation.

Comment: Are you returning the entire array of messages, or are you returning individual messages and would like to know what position they had?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an auto increment field but you can use functions to generate and administrate sequence :
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ ﻿

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a **timestamp** rather than a numerical value. By using a timestamp, you can keep the ordering of the subdocument and make other use of it.